# how to pass oauth2 token to mashup filab?

Tags: oauth-2.0, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I have followed the whole process to obtain an oauth2 access token from the Identity Manager (I get it) and I want to pass it to a web application developed on Filab Mashup but embedded in my own web. 
In my Mashup application I need  get the oauth token for to access Orion Context Broker information but I don't know how to pass it.
This is the code of my callback URL where I obtain the token:

```
<?php
//get the code from url
$code = $_GET["code"];

//print_r($code);

//application specific declarations
$domain = "www.talkysync.com";
$clientId = "my_client_ID";
$clientSecret = "my_client_secret";
//access token url
$url = 'https://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/token';

//payload params for the request token
$payload = 'grant_type=authorization_code&code='. $code .'&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.talkysync.com%2Ffiware_login%2Fcallback.php';

//base64(client_id:client_secret)
$cadena = $clientId . ":" .$clientSecret;
$base = base64_encode($cadena);

//extra header for the request
$header = array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization: Basic ". $base);

//actual request implementation
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_close($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
;
//get the access token from the json response

$jsonData = json_decode($output,true);
$access_token = $jsonData["access_token"];

//start a session and set the access token to it
session_start();
$_SESSION["X-Auth-Token"] = $access_token;
$_SESSION["code"] = $code;

header("Location: fiware.php");
?>
```

And this is the code of fiware.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["X-Auth-Token"])){  
    header('Location: login.php');
}else{
    header('Location: https://mashup.lab.fiware.org/ertonio/Talkykar?mode=embedded');
}
?>
```

But in the mashup application I always have an anonymous connection because I don't know how to pass it the token.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently is not possible to create an embedded WireCloud URL including the credentials. Seems interesting and worth implementing it, but also seems a lot of work, so don't expect it to be implemented in a short period of time.

Regarding, accessing the orion context broker from WireCloud, take a look into section "3.2.1. Using Orion Context Broker" on the [WireCloud's course](http://edu.fiware.org/course/view.php?id=53#section-3) available on the FIWARE Academy.